# Is there a way to set an element that is NaN to 0?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have an array that looks like [[1,1,0,1, NaN], [NaN, 2, 3,4,5], [1,1,1,1,1]]. I have to do some optimization calculations with these arrays but due to the presence of these NaNs, my solution also contains NaN. I tried iterating through the array and setting the NaN to 0 but that didn't work.

'''for i in s:
       for j in i:
           if type(j) != int:
               j = 0
'''

I know arrays are immutable. I was wondering if there is any other way to do this?

Comment: one of the solution could be this one:
const arr = [[1,1,0,1, NaN], [NaN, 2, 3,4,5], [1,1,1,1,1]];
console.log(arr.map(x => x.filter(num => !isNaN(num))));
This is in javascript but all this function should exist also in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy as this:

```
a=np.array([[1,1,0,1, np.nan], [np.nan, 2, 3,4,5], [1,1,1,1,1]])
np.nan_to_num(a)
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`nan_to_num`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html)

or you can make that a dataframe and use pandas [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
     0  1   2   3   4
0   1.0 1   0   1   NaN
1   NaN 2   3   4   5.0
2   1.0 1   1   1   1.0
```

you can do `df.fillna(0)`

```
      0 1   2   3   4
0   1.0 1   0   1   0.0
1   0.0 2   3   4   5.0
2   1.0 1   1   1   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, but should work:

```
for i,subArray in enumerate(s):
    for j,element in enumerate(subArray):
        try:
            float(element)
            # This will fail if the element cannot be converted
        except:
            s[i][j] = 0
```

Hope this helps!